# how to use __func__ or __FUNCTION__ constant in recursive code?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

for example consider this single factorial:

```
int factorial(int number) {
  int temp;
  if(number <= 1) return 1;
  temp = number * __FUNCTION__(number - 1);
  return temp;
}
```

It gives:

```
error: '__FUNCTION__' cannot be used as a function
```

The idea is using this constant instead of function name so if I change the name of the function it wouldn't be needed to look in the rest of the code to update the name wherever function calls itself.

Comment: Instead of renaming you can introduce the new name you want that defers to `factorial`. You can also do so while moving `factorial` to e.g. a `detail` namespace.

Comment: Note that `__FUNCTION__` expands to a string literal (in quotes), i.e. `"factorial"` (or its name-mangled equivalent) in this case.

Comment: Most modern editors have a global find/replace. I could do this change in about 3 seconds with vi, even if the function was called from 100 differnt places in a file. :%s/factorial/anotherName/g

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of maintainable code.

Comment: Sometimes questions remind me of this infamous quote: [*Pray, Mr Babbage, ...*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't because `__FUNCTION__` is probably reserved by the implementation, and it expands to the function name (in string format).

Besides changing the name, you might want to use a macro instead of a constant:

```
#define MY_FUNCTION factorial

int MY_FUNCTION(int number) {
  int temp;
  if(number <= 1) return 1;
  temp = number * MY_FUNCTION(number - 1);
  return temp;
}
```

**Personally, I don't see the point of this.** Granted, you only change the function name in one place, but is it worth it?

Comment: I still don't get why it can't be used. It expands to the function name - okay, why isn't the expansion result treated as proper code?